# Como usar where com filtro em C# entre duas tabelas (one to many)?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, sql-server, .net, entity-framework

Usando C# e EntityFramework:
Tenho duas tabelas com relacionamento entre elas de "um para muitos".
Gostaria de fazer dois Gets em uma controller:

O 1o que me trouxesse os dados da tabela que não tivessem ligação com a outra tabela.

O 2o que me trouxesse apenas os dados que tem ligação com a outra tabela.

Tendo a tabela abaixo como exemplo:

Gostaria que a 1a busca me trouxesse apenas o hulk e o pantera negra, pois estes não possuem armas.

Em seguida a outra busca me trouxesse o capitão américa e o thor.

### tabela1

| Id | Nome |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Hulk |
| 2 | Capitão America |
| 3 | Pantera Negra |
| 4 | Thor |

### tabela2

| Id | Nome | HeroiId |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Escudo | 2 |
| 2 | Martelo | 4 |

Para o 1o caso eu tentei abaixo:

```
public ActionResult<IEnumerable<Heroi>> Get()
{
    return _context.Herois.Where(c => c.Armas != null).ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você precisará usar operadores de consulta complexa: https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/ef/core/querying/complex-query-operators

Para trazer apenas "hulk" e "pantera negra", vocë precisa fazer um LEFT JOIN. O LINQ não possui um operador de LEFT JOIN nativo, mas você pode usar esse padrão para chegar ao mesmo resultado. Crie um GroupJoin entre as duas tabelas e depois nivele o grupo usando SelectMany com DefaultIfEmpty na origem do grupo para corresponder a nulo quando o interno não tiver um elemento relacionado. Segue o exemplo:

```
var Herois = from t1 in context.Set<Tab1>()
                 join t2 in context.Set<Tab2>()
                    on t1.Id equals t2.HeroiId into grouping
                 from t2 in grouping.DefaultIfEmpty()
                    where t2.HeroiId == null
                 select new { t1 };
```

A query gerada é:

```
SELECT [t].[id], [t].[name]  
FROM [tab1] AS [t]  
LEFT JOIN [tab2] AS [t0] 
    ON [t].[id] = [t0].[heroi_id]  
WHERE [t0].[heroi_id] IS NULL
```

Já para trazer "capitão américa" e "thor", você precisa fazer um JOIN simples entre as duas tabelas. Lembre-se que as tabelas envolvidas precisam ter PRIMARY KEY e FOREIGN KEY definidas no banco de dados.

```
var Herois = from t1 in context.Set<Tab1>()
                 join t2 in context.Set<Tab2>()
                    on t1.Id equals t2.HeroiId
                 select new { t1 };
```

A query gerada é:

```
SELECT [t].[id], [t].[name]  
FROM [tab1] AS [t]  
INNER JOIN [tab2] AS [t0] 
ON [t].[id] = [t0].[heroi_id]
```

Answer (score 1):

Neste cenário você pode utilizar o LINQ com uma propriedade de navegação do tipo ICollection, ficaria assim:

```
public class Heroi
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }

    // EF Navigation
    public ICollection<Arma> Armas { get; set; }
}

public class Arma
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public int HeroiId { get; set; }

    public Heroi Heroi { get; set; }
}
```

No controller você faz:

```
var herois = context.Herois.Include(x => x.Armas).ToList();

var heroisComArma = herois.Where(x =>  x.Armas.Any());
var heroisSemArma = herois.Where(x => !x.Armas.Any());
```

Comment: Perfeito cara! Não conhecia a função Any. Valeu a dica muito simples, prático e rápido! Muito obrigado!